# Testing local methods containing service calls using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am facing an issue with testing a local method in my Angular JS controller.

I need to test `retrieveRuleDetails` method which contains a service call, but not able to proceed. Please help to test the below code:

```
var retrieveRuleDetails = function(feeId, ruleId) {
    $rootScope.triggerLoading(true);
    FeesRulesService.getRule(feeId, ruleId)
        .then(getRuleSuccess)
        .catch(getRuleFail);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best would be to pass  FeesRulesService as a paramter - a spy in jasmine
and than to test getRule is invoked

```
 FeesRulesServiceMock= {
      getRule: function(feeId,ruleId) {

      }
    };

    spyOn(FeesRulesServiceMock, 'getRule');

retrieveRuleDetails(feeId,ruleId,FeesRulesServiceMock)

it("bla bla",function(){
expect(FeesRulesServiceMock.getRule).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(FeesRulesServiceMock.getRule).toHaveBeenCalledWith(feeId,ruleId);

});
```

Comment: then how can I check the then and catch statements :
then(getRuleSuccess)
        .catch(getRuleFail);

Comment: because then is called on the result of getRule , you could make the getRule return another spy , and make an expect on it , and for the catch it would be about the same - though I think TDD wise it would be better to separate it to different test , since the point of a test is to direct you to the exact problem.